# Every 10 seconds router ping delays for 1 second

Tags: wireless-networking, router

Pinging my wifi router I noticed that every 10 seconds one ping takes more then a second to reply. And that is perfectly looped for 10 seconds. I don't see any strange traffic sent from my PC (checked with wireshark). Another computer in my network does not have any connection troubles. So advice me please on where to look next?

Example of trace:

```
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=1320ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What actually happened is a new neighbor settled in apartment next to mine and he had a lot of radio tools working on wifi frequency (few his routers and a lot of home tools connecting to those). When I checked possible free channels that I can use with my current frequency - all those seemed to by very busy by all my neighbors. The easiest solution for me was to settle a cabled LAN connection to the internet, which I did. For those who for some reasons cannot put a cable - you may try to switch your modem to different frequency using 802.11a or 802.11n with 5 Ghz or 802.11b g with 2.4 Ghz and trying different channels there. Connect to your router with LAN cable, run its web app configuration tool and see what settings it support.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem, but I found the solution. One drive + windows update.
You can run the ping test in safe mode to confirm that. Here is how to research and fix the problem. 
https://hitech-us.com/articles/entry/292/Ping-spikes-on-Wi-Fi-every-10-seconds.-%E2%80%93-Solved.

Comment: Welcome to [su]! Thanks for sharing the solution. Please add the relevant steps directly in your answer, because the link is likely to disappear in a few years, making your current answer unusable.

Comment: The link has disappeared.